# AS3 Dynamic TextField not updating

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

This is nuts

I have a dynamic textfield on my stage with the instance name `trackText`.

I have declared `public var trackText:TextField;`.

When I trace `trackText.text` it gives me exactly what I expect but the actual text on the stage does not update.

anyone have any ideas as to why?

```
public var trackText:TextField;

trackText.text = audioPlayer.currentSong.title;

trace("trackText = " + trackText.text);

// gives me what i expect "track 1" etc..
```

but the text on the stage still says "loading..."

any help would be great ta

Comment: Agree with Tomofei, people will stop helping you Mark. All we ask for is the measly rep that we get when you accept and or upvote an answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have one on the stage, then creating a new one with

```
public var trackText:TextField;
```

doesn't link it to the one on the stage but still allows it to have its own text as your trace statement shows. You would first need to say something like:

```
trackText = textFieldOnStageInstanceName;
```

In order to hook them up. Then you can change the text as you have done!

Note: You don't even need to declare a variable and instead just reference the instance name in the code through something like:

```
theDoc.textFieldOnStageInstanceName.text = "Yay!";
```

Hope this helped!!

Answer (score 2):

Embed the chars you are using: properties panel -> embed

Comment: This solved my problem, because the text field was being referenced correctly but the text still wasn't updating.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you haven't assigned correctly to the textField.

Try increasing the width of the textField, and set its maxChars property.